# Correct Way To Create My Customize Background Of Tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have a requirement to create UITableView background that are include of small horizontal stripes of gray and white (very small).

I thought about this ways :

-One way, create png file of one cell background.set this to all cells.
-Second way, create png file for the table.

-Now, i wonder if there is a third way, i create only 2 horizontal stripes (gray and white) in a png file, i with some code, this png will be duplicate for all the table background.

Hope i'm clear here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The first way it makes no sense at least you want the background to scroll while scrolling the table.

The second way seems the best way for me. It is straight forward and I don't think you need to get complicated into the others. But if you want to make your image small and than repeat it you can do that something like this:

```
UIImage *yourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:<#imageName#>];
    self.tableView.backgroundImage = [yourImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:yourImage.size.width topCapHeight:0];
```